# java - Generating a random number in range

Tags: java

```
Random random = new Random();
int x = scanner.nextInt(bound:20)+1;
```

(bound:20) is not working to generate a random number from 1 to 20.
what is the mistake I have done in this code?

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = scanner.nextInt(20) + 1;
```

Just remove "bound :". The nextInt method expects an integer as an upper bound. So giving 20 as an argument is enough.

Comment: Thanks!! But I have seen the (Bound) used in a video tutorial in exactly same line of code. Does the java version matter?

Comment: Thats probably just additional information (the name of the function's parameter) provided by the IDE.